# How can I add an entity reference to a list entity refences of a node with rules?

Tags: rules, entities

I have a node with a entity reference field with multiple values.

How can I add an entity reference to a this list with rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your setup and where you want to trigger the rule, but you would do this with PHP code added as a rule action:

```
$node = node_load(YOUR_NODE_ID);
$node->field_you_want_to_save[]['target_id'] = NEW_ENTITY_REFERENCE_ID;
$node->save();
```

Comment: You're welcome :) if this solved your question, click on the green check sign right next to the answer to accept it as a solution.